# Get 503 response code from youtube, when scraping comments with python

Tags: python, youtube, web-scraping, comments

I'm trying to scrape comments on YouTube videos with python, but I have problems with `503` response code.

When send post request with python requests for loading more comments I get some "JavaScript Object Notation" file, with "page_token" and "html" inside it, and that's okay, but when I send second request for more comments I get `503` response code.

I know what it means. How can  I solve the problem?

Comment: Please post your code and the full stack trace that comes with the error, both are needed to solve any problem.

Comment: Here is the code http://pastebin.com/B6Z812kT

Comment: And i do not have any stack trace, just get "Response <[503]>" and that's it, Thanks man.